# accessing property in text response python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to access a response from a http request using python requests library.
The response comes in a text format, json is not available

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('http://url.com')
print(resp.text)
=> login=http://new_url.com?anylock=9f8s9g0asd&calls=vlsdu2
```

I need the value after `login=` so would it be a good approach to use `resp.split('login=')[1]`

Comment: That seems reasonable, if you only expect `login=` to be present once and immediately before your desired string.

Comment: Yes, would only be login= value always. Another idea I thought to be cleaner print(list(filter(None, x.split('login_url='))))  but that is performing some extra steps. Is it better to perform less number of operations to get the final value, or should it be okay regardless?

Comment: In my opinion, you should prefer more readable code, and don't try to optimize prematurely. It is easier for me to understand what `resp.split('login=')[1]` does than `list(filter(None, x.split('login_url=')))`.

Comment: got it. i think this method works too: new = dict(x.split('=', 1) for x in resp.split()) assuming that the first = is splitting the login_url